# again and again this error, i can't solve it when running react app

Tags: reactjs

Failed to compile
./src/index.js 1:39
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:39)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/I'm-cx0140/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
> | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
> |
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the  node modules folder and redoing `npm install`?

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading react scripts-

Go into the package.json and changed the `react-scripts to 4.0.1` and type `npm install`(terminal) and re-run it.

Comment: I tried it also with react-scripts 4.0.1, and with 4.0.2 but not working

Comment: @Harikrushnachavada check how you named your folder. It should not contain any spaces or ( ' ) in there.

Comment: I can't understand exact what are you say?  I should what to do for fix this error

Comment: The ( ' ) in I'm-cx0140 try replacing that to Im-cx0140